# python socketserver timeout

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

I'm implementing a simple server which should print a message if nothing is received for 3 seconds.

**Handler**

```
class SingleTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            message = self.rfile.readline().strip()
            print message
```

**Server**

```
class SimpleServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    timeout = 3

    def handle_timeout(self):
        print "Timeout"

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass):
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
```

Here I'm extending the `TCPServer` for testing the timeout method.
I've set the `timeout` atribute to `3`. According to the docs, if that time passes and no messages are sent to the client `handle_timeout()` is called which, in my case, just prints 'Timeout'.

> BaseServer.timeout
>
> Timeout duration, measured in seconds, or None if no timeout is desired. 
>    If handle_request() receives no incoming requests within the
>    timeout period, the handle_timeout() method is called.

I start the server, and observe it's output. When i connect to it and send some messages, they are normally printed. However, if I don't send anything for 3 seconds or more, nothing happens. As if the `timeout` and `handle_timeout()` haven't been implemented.

What could be the source of this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I dropped the `socketserver` module and went directly with `socket` module, in which timeout worked.

```
TIMEOUT = 3
HOST = '192.0.0.202'              
PORT = 2000             

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    conn.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
    while 1:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            #Do things

        except socket.timeout:
            #Timeout occurred, do things

        if not data or P=='end':
            print 'Connection lost. Listening for a new controller.' 
            break

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

you must not call server_forever() method for app loop.
try this one instead:

```
while True:
  self.handle_request()
```

handle_timeout() works for me then.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try declare the timeout at `self.timeout` (i.e make it a instance field instead of class variable ?)

EDIT (here is the code)

```
def handle_request(self):
           """Handle one request, possibly blocking.

          Respects self.timeout.
          """
          # Support people who used socket.settimeout() to escape
          # handle_request before self.timeout was available.
          timeout = self.socket.gettimeout()
          if timeout is None:
               timeout = self.timeout
           elif self.timeout is not None:
               timeout = min(timeout, self.timeout)
           fd_sets = select.select([self], [], [], timeout)
           if not fd_sets[0]:
               self.handle_timeout()
               return
           self._handle_request_noblock()
```

Comment: Will try to implement this if a prettier solution doesn't show up. It seems like an unnecessary hack with the existence of the `handle_timeout()`?

Comment: From the code it seems the "static"/class timeout variable isn't taken into account :( so maybe changing the socket timeout or make it to return None will help (since then, self.timeout could take its role)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the document of [serve_forever()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseServer.serve_forever):

> Handle requests until an explicit shutdown() request. Poll for shutdown every poll_interval seconds. **Ignores self.timeout.** If you need to do periodic tasks, do them in another thread

So the `serve_forever()` will only check if `shutdown()` is called every `poll_interval` whose default value is 0.5 seconds. And only `handle_request()` care about the `timeout`.

Here is the code for [serve_forever()](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/SocketServer.py#l221) and [handle_request()](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/SocketServer.py#l264).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what do you mean by "[the server] should print a message if nothing is received for 3 seconds."?

Do you mean that the server should ...

1. shutdown if it hadn't any new requests in certain period?
2. close a connection if it isn't finished in a certain period?

In the first case you can use `BaseServer.timeout` but you would also have to use `BaseServer.handle_request()` instead of `BaseServer.server_forever()`.

In the second case you should have set the timeout for the `SingleTCPHandler`:

```
class SingleTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    timeout = 3
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            message = self.rfile.readline().strip()
            print message
```

For people who want to use their own implementation of `BaseRequestHandler`:

```
class MyRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.request.settimeout(3)
```